# How to customize the URL per-service using Knative + Kourier + Operator

Tags: knative-serving

We are using the Knative operator (generated from Helmify) and trying to change the hostname *only* not the domain (or anything else). Everything is working fine so far.

**How can we change the hostname of the service (on a per-service basis) rather than using the service name and leave everything else as-is?**

It seems customizing the `domain-template` does not work but changes are being recognized because I can "break" things like the `ingress-class` and get the expected failures.

```
NAMESPACE    NAME    URL                                         LATESTCREATED   LATESTREADY   READY   REASON
serverless   hello   http://hello.serverless.svc.cluster.local   hello-00001     hello-00001   True
```

We are trying to change the hostname

- From http://**hello**.serverless.svc.cluster.local
- To http://**hello-world**.serverless.svc.cluster.local

Everything else can be left as-is:

```
serverless               hello                                                ExternalName
serverless               hello-00001                                          ClusterIP                                         
serverless               hello-00001-private                                  ClusterIP
```

Following these instructions https://julz.github.io/docs/v0.20/serving/using-a-custom-domain-per-service/#verify-the-changes until I realized they were not the official/latest docs.

The service being deployed with a custom annotation (note the annotation that is meant to be used for the hostname instead of the service name):

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: serverless
  annotations:
    custom-hostname: hello-world
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-registry
      containers:
        - image: docker/sandbox:example
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: TARGET
              value: "World"
```

The operator manifest where we try to customize the `domain-template` ending up with this in the `config-network` configmap:

```yaml
apiVersion: operator.knative.dev/v1beta1
kind: KnativeServing
metadata:
  name: knative-serving
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  ingress:
    kourier:
      enabled: true
  config:
    network:
      domain-template: |-
        {{if index .Annotations "custom-hostname" -}}
          {{- index .Annotations "custom-hostname" -}}
        {{else -}}
          {{- .Name }}.{{ .Namespace -}}
        {{end -}}
        .{{ .Domain }}
      ingress-class: "kourier.ingress.networking.knative.dev"
```